# Hosting a WCF webservice and WCF Net.Tcp service in the same IIS container?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, iis, nettcpbinding

I'm trying to build a system which consists of:

1. A centralized IIS component
2. A Client application written in .Net
3. A Third party application.

The .Net Client should on startup connect to a WCF Net.Tcp Binding on the IIS application and register it's self as a consumer of requests (Callbacks).

The Third party application will then make Web Service calls to the IIS server which will farm out the request to the .Net Clients.

How do I host mutliple WCF services IIS? Is this possible?

I assume that I'd have to instantiate the services in the web.config as endpoints but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [multiple SVC files hosted within the same application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx) or you could use [MVC-style Routing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/14/wcf-extensibility-servicehostfactory.aspx) to establish the multiple [`ServiceHosts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx).

[Here is an MSDN example on hosting WCF within IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx) using web.config and SVC files.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'd gotten that far by searching the internet after I asked the question. I'm still having trouble getting hte net.TCP binding to work under IIS. See this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316457/cant-access-net-tcp-service-from-wcf-test-client/10316856#10316856

Comment: I hadn't actually noticed you'd already posted an answer to that question. Thanks.