# Can't Access Net TCP service From WCF Test Client

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

I'm trying to run two WCF services from within IIS one is a web service and one is a Net TCP Binding Service.

Here is a simulcrum of my Web.config (I've anonymized the service name):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ServerService">
        <endpoint address="ServerService" 
                  binding="netTcpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="" 
                  name="NetTcpEndPoint" 
                  contract="IServerService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8523/"/>
            <add baseAddress="htt://localhost:8523/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

      <service name="MyWebService">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration=""
                  name="AACCWSEndPoint"
                  contract="IMyWebService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8523/IMyWebService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

When I run this in the IDE it opens a page running on port 51953 and I can get the WSDL for the webservice by browsing to http://localhost:51953/WebService.svc?wsdl (Note the port is different).
I can't seem to get the WSDL by changing to port to what I've specified in the webconfig file (8523).

When I point the WcfTestClient app at "net.tcp://localhost:8523/ServerService and it gives me an error saying that it can't access the meta data, which as far as I can see I've configured (the second end point in the service).

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried changing the port number on the project properties to 8523 as suggested that didn't seem to work, I've also tried changint the address of the mex endpoint to "ServerService\mex" the test client spent some time churning but then it threw the following error:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   net.tcp://localhost:8523/ServerService If this is a Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please
>   check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified
>   address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the
>   MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error    URI: net.tcp://localhost:8523/ServerService     Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'net.tcp://localhost:8523/ServerService'.    You have tried to create
>   a channel to a service that does not support .Net Framing. It is
>   possible that you are encountering an HTTP endpoint.    Expected
>   record type 'PreambleAck', found '72'.

I'm going to keep digging but I'd appreciate any help.

**UPDATE 2:**

I've changed the mex endpoint to a mexTcpBinding:
Here is the service tag:

```
    <endpoint address="ServerServiceWS"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration=""
              name="WSEndPoint"
              contract="IServerService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexTcpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8523/"/>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8523/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

Still no luck. Just to be sure I am entering the correct url into the tester the Url I am using is:

```
net.tcp://localhost:8523/ServerService
```

I've also Tried:

```
net.tcp://localhost:8523/mex
```

and

```
net.tcp://localhost:8523/
```

All of which give me some variation of the following error:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   net.tcp://localhost:8523/ServerService If this is a Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please
>   check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified
>   address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the
>   MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error    URI: net.tcp://localhost:8523/ServerService    Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'net.tcp://localhost:8523/ServerService'.    You have tried to create
>   a channel to a service that does not support .Net Framing. It is
>   possible that you are encountering an HTTP endpoint.    Expected
>   record type 'PreambleAck', found '72'.

**UPDATE 3**

FWIW I think there might be a bigger problem with my WEb.config Here is what it currently looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ServerService">
        <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="netTcpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="DefaultBindingConfig" 
                  name="NetTcpEndPoint" 
                  contract="IServerService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexTcpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" 
                  bindingConfiguration="mexBinding"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8523/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

      <service name="MyWebService">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration=""
                  name="MyWSEndPoint"
                  contract="IMyWebService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"
                  bindingConfiguration="mexHttpBinding"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8523/MyWebService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="DefaultBindingConfig"
                 maxConnections="5"
                 portSharingEnabled="true" >
        </binding>
        <binding name="mexBinding"
                 portSharingEnabled="true">
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
      <mexTcpBinding>
        <binding name="mexTcpBinding"/>
      </mexTcpBinding>
      <mexHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mexHttpBinding"/>
      </mexHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServerServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="MexBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" policyVersion="Policy15"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I can browse to the Webservice and that allows me to get the WSDL using ?wsdl but if I put the Adddress http://localhost:8523/MyWebService into the WCF tester it throws an error too.

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:8523/MyWebService
>   If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you
>   have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at
>   the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please
>   refer to the MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error    URI: http://localhost:8523/MyWebService    Metadata contains
>   a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://localhost:8523/MyWebService'.    An error occurred while
>   receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:8523/MyWebService.
>   This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP
>   protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being
>   aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See
>   server logs for more details.    The underlying connection was closed:
>   An unexpected error occurred on a receive.    Unable to read data from
>   the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed
>   by the remote host.    An existing connection was forcibly closed by
>   the remote hostHTTP GET Error    URI:
>   http://localhost:8523/MyWebService    There was an error downloading
>   'http://localhost:8523/MyWebService'.    The request failed with HTTP
>   status 404: Not Found.

I think the issue is either something to do with paths or I'm just putting the wrong URL into the test application. Either that or I've still not configured the meta data correctly.

Comment: Note the second base address is the result of me trying to expose the same service as a web service, I've tried it without that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: `<add baseAddress="htt://localhost:8523/"/>` has a protocol (HTTP) typo

Comment: Would that stop the net.tcp service from working or would it be used by the metadata exchange?

Answer (score 5):

For the HTTP endpoint, you need to [reconfigure the Project Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178108.aspx) so that it starts your web.config defined endpoint at port 8523 if hosted using IIS Express. Use specific port (8523) instead of auto-assigned port (51953).

For the TCP metadata, you need to support a TCP-enabled mex endpoint ([`mexTcpBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967279.aspx)).

```xml
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Comment: Should the address for the meta data endpoint be "mex" or should it be in a sub directory of the service it's describing?

Comment: @OmarKooheji That should be "mex", at least the WCF Test Client wants it that way.

Answer (score 1):

The net.tcp and HTTP bindings must be set on different ports on IIS.
It can be tested with the same port or different. It will crash in the first case. Also, you can use whatever port numbers you want. In this case, the TCP port can be changed to 8524. It's just that you cannot use two separate protocols on the same port. On the other hand, the base addresses make sense only for self-hosted services. Here the base address is determined by the URL from IIS.

Comment: Could you provide more information? Like, reference documentation, port values example... ?

Comment: This may be linked to the "add more information" stuff; would you update your answer with your last comment, it would be more valuable ;-)

Answer (score 0):

just try to keep this  as it is, and changing your service inside and paste it inside your config file, it should work perfectly. 
to test the net.tcp you can use SvcUtil.exe

```
       <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="MyWCFServices.HelloWorldService">
    <endpoint
         binding="netTcpBinding"
         bindingConfiguration="ultra"
         contract="MyWCFServices.IHelloWorldService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"  />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8086/HelloWorldService.svc" />
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8081/HelloWorldService.svc" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="ultra"
         maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
         maxBufferSize="2147483647"
         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
         portSharingEnabled="false"
         transactionFlow="false"
         listenBacklog="2147483647" >
      <security mode="None">
        <message clientCredentialType="None"/>
        <transport protectionLevel="None" clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
      <reliableSession enabled="false"/>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: two more configuration on IIS ...    <br / >